# Return matching row values in other columns from stacked columns with =FILTER()

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I stacked columns S through AB in this sheet.

[image: this sheet]

with a `=filter()` function:

```
=filter({Storage!S2:S;Storage!U2:U;Storage!W2:W;Storage!Y2:Y;Storage!AA2:AA}, len({Storage!S2:S;Storage!U2:U;Storage!W2:W;Storage!Y2:Y;Storage!AA2:AA}))
```

and it ends up,

[image: like this],
as desired

Is there any way to extract the values from other columns like Map, Side, Site, and Win/Loss from the exact rows the filter function returned?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you want to get "Death" and "Rd Time" of all rounds stacked on each other and join Map, Round, Side, Site, Strat?, Results and Plant? columns to the stacked columns, ok there is a better way than `FILTER` formula.

In the second sheet where you want the stacked columns on A2 Paste this formula

```
=QUERY({Data!H2:I,Data!A2:G;Data!J2:K,Data!A2:G;Data!L2:M,Data!A2:G;Data!N2:O,Data!A2:G;Data!P2:Q,Data!A2:G}," Select * Where Col1 is not null ")
```

to get the desired result as shown in the image.

You can also make a copy for the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h_pBLLY5ovQafKmOfVOu_zBmzmr-eTJmK0Ki4fS5lO4/edit?usp=sharing) , include yours to get quicker responses.

Breakdown:

1. A combination of [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function and `{}` arrays to order columns without the need for intermediate tables
2. `,` to join columns
3. `;` to stack columns

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there any way to join specific columns rather than the A2:G range? E.G only Map, or only Side, or another column further down the sheet?

Comment: @Fettuccine Yes there is, replace A2:G where you found it with the desired column Like this `=QUERY({Data!H2:I,Data!A2:G...`  TO `=QUERY({Data!H2:I,Data!E2:G...`, i updated the spreadsheet with a new sheet "Stacked 02" take a look.